# Is this a typical growth habit for a cactus?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, cactus

I was re-potting my 9+ year old cactus to a bigger pot yesterday and noticed a sizable portion of its stem is submerged. Is this a typical growth habit? What are the chances that this stem might rot and cause issues down the line? Also, if anyone knows the species that would be helpful.

[image: Cactus transplant]

Answer (score 4):

It's an Echinocactus grusonii, that has been standing in the wrong place for maybe two years, thus the elongated growth in the middle. Typically too dark or to warm in winter. Then it has been moved to an apprpriate place where it continous its normal growth, that is, becoming a large sphere eventually. It has than be planted deeper, maybe to make it look better. If the drowned part will eventually rot i can't tell you, this depends heaviky on the environment. Carefull watering, especially in winter will lessen the chance of rotting.

Comment: Ah, so it looks like it should be growing more as a sphere than an elongated shape. By careful watering, do you mean it should be watered much less in winter?

Comment: Exactly. It depends a little on the kind of cactus, e.g. The epiphyte rain forest cacti should be watered normally, whereas the desert cacti should be watered only very occasionally. I water my cacti (residing in central europe) only once or twice from october to april, hibernating them in a lucid, unheated attic.